# Is QUERYOPTION_AWAITDATA necessary for a non-Tailable cursor

Tags: mongodb-java

Below mentioned problem occurred while migrating mongodb from 2.x version to 3.x, where QUERYOPTION_AWAITDATA was used on a non-tailable cursor.

Problem statement:
In the earlier version i.e, in 2.11.4 version of MongoDB-Java driver , we were allowed to use QUERYOPTION_AWAITDATA on a non-Tailable cursor.
But in version 3.2 of  MongoDB-Java driver, we are only allowed to use QUERYOPTION_AWAITDATA on a Tailable cursor.

Question:
What difference was it making by adding QUERYOPTION_AWAITDATA to an non-Tailable cursor in 2.11.4. 
If there is a reason for having QUERYOPTION_AWAITDATA for an non-Tailable cursor, then how can this be addressed in 3.2 version of mongodb-java Drvier.?

Is QUERYOPTION_AWAITDATA necessary for a non-Tailable cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not necessary.  I'd consider it a bug that 2.x allows you to set that on a non-tailable cursor and that 3.x just fixed the glitch.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!! If it was a bug then we are good to not include QUERYOPTION_AWAITDATA for an non-tailable cursor in 3.x.